# Why is event.clientX incorrectly showing as 0 in firefox for dragend event?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, mouse-position

The alert from `dragend` is showing `mouseX` as zero no matter where it is currently. This works fine in Chrome so not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
function move(e,obj,but){
    if(typeof(obj) === 'string'){
        obj = document.getElementById(obj) ;
    }
    
    if(typeof(but) === 'string'){
        but = document.getElementById(but) ;
    }

    //elementCoord(but) ;//get the current coords of the button &
    elementCoord(obj) ;//the container
    
    e = e || window.event ;
    var mouseX = e.clientX ;
    var mouseY = e.clientY ;
            
    //alert('mouseX='+mouseX+', but.XCoord '+but.XCoord) ;
    var diffX = Math.abs(obj.XCoord - mouseX) ;
    var diffY = Math.abs(obj.YCoord - mouseY) ;
    
    but.addEventListener("dragend",function(evt){
        evt = evt || window.event ;
        mouseX = evt.clientX ;
        mouseY = evt.clientY ;
        obj.style.left = mouseX - diffX + 'px';
        obj.style.top = mouseY - diffY + 'px';
        alert('mouseX='+mouseX+' diffX='+diffX) ;
        }
    ,false) ;
    
}
```

Forgot to mention, `elementCoord` just gets the offset of an object adding it as a property. It works fine in all browsers.

Comment: `dragend` event applies to the source element, which is the one being dragged. Use `drop` event's `clientX` and `clientY` to get the coordinate of the target element instead of using `dragend`.

Comment: FWIW, here is the Bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505521

Comment: Browser differences: In IE10 clientX is the same in "dragstart", "dragend", "drop" but in Chrome/Firefox "dragend" is relative to the drag source (drag right and clientX is negative).

Comment: Just a note to remine folks to also prefer `clientX` and `clientY` over` x` and `y ` in the `drag` part if you're trying to record where in the element the click was to start the drag...

Comment: I'm getting this issue even for `drag` events

Comment: I know it's been 8 years since you asked this question, and 11 years since it was reported to FF, but I finally came up with a solution with working demo, hope this helps!

Answer (score 11):

This is officially an issue with Firefox -- [Bugzilla: Bug #505521, Set screen coordinates during HTML5 drag event](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505521#c80).  I'll quote jbmj to summarize, and I will bold the original developer they are quoting...

> I can't believe that this comment
> "**Note though that it doesn't specify what the properties should be set to, just that they should be set and we currently set them to 0.**"
> from 11years ago is still state of the art.

I was inspired by Jay's comment, to use the "drop" event.  But that was only a comment, so let me thresh it out into an answer.

Our problem: `dragend` event has `e.clientY` and `e.clientX` set to 0.

How we will solve it: `document`'s `drop` event *also fires* at the same exact time as the element we are dragging's `dragend` event.  And: `drop` ***will have the correct values for `e.clientY` and `e.clientX`.***

***Two working demos, 100% JavaScript-Only Solution***: SO Code Snippet and [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/hiyabib/edit?html,css,js,console,output).  The SO Code Snippet console sometimes gobbles up the dragged element in the console, and JSBin gave me more consistent results.

```js
var startx = 0;
var starty = 0;
dragStartHandler = function(e) {
  startx = e.clientX;
  starty = e.clientY;
}

dragOverHandler = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}

dragEndHandler = function(e) {
  if(!startx || !starty) {
    return false;
  }
  
  var diffx = e.clientX - startx;
  var diffy = e.clientY - starty;
  
  var rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();

var offset = { 
                top: rect.top + window.scrollY, 
                left: rect.left + window.scrollX, 
            };
  
  var newleft = offset.left + diffx;
  var newtop = offset.top + diffy;
  
  e.target.style.position = 'absolute';
  e.target.style.left = newleft + 'px';
  e.target.style.top = newtop + 'px';
  
  startx = 0;
  starty = 0;
}

document.getElementsByClassName("draggable")[0].addEventListener('dragstart', dragStartHandler);

document.addEventListener('dragover', dragOverHandler);
document.addEventListener('drop', dragEndHandler);
```

```css
.draggable {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: move;
  width:250px;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <BR><BR><BR>

  <div id="draggable1" class="draggable" draggable="true">
    Hey, try to drag this element!
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**Explanation:**

- `dragStartHandler()` : This is bound to the draggable element.  Here, all we do is record the current x/y coordinates at start.
- `dragOverHandler()` : This is bound to the document, so that we can override the default dragover behavior.  This is needed to do any type of drag & dropping.
- `dragEndHandler()` : This is bound to the `document`'s `drop`.  Normally, we would want this to bind to the `element`'s `dragend`, but since `clientY` and `clientX` are missing, we bind it to the document.  This just does exactly what you'd want to happen when dragend is called, except you have x/y coordinates.

Answer (score 10):

There is an [old bug with firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505521) about drag events not being provided with user pointer information

I have found that almost all drag related events in firefox now do publish user pointer information:

- ✅ `"dragstart"`
- ✅ `"dragenter"`
- ✅ `"dragleave"`
- ✅ `"dragover"`
- ✅ `"drop"`
- ✅ `"dragend"`
- ❌ `"drag"`

> Tested in firefox version 99

So to answer the original question: `event.clientX` will no longer always be `0` in `dragend` in firefox

---

If you need to get pointer information during a drag (ie what `"drag"` would usually give you) then you can do the following:

1. Add an event listener to a fairly high `EventTarget` (eg `window`) and listen for `"dragover"` events.

- `dragover` fires whenever you are over a potential drop target, which is every `Element`
- By adding an event listener to a high `EventTarget` (eg `window`) you can leverage [event bubbling](https://domevents.dev/) to capture all the `dragover` events for all `Element`s in the `document`

2. Profit : effectively get a `drag` event by repurposing `dragover`

```js
window.addEventListener('dragover', (event) => {
  // event.clientX and friends are correctly set!
});
```

Comment: i thought i was crazy but when i looked it up it really is the truth, thanks. They have a bug for 14 years that they can't fix, very nice firefox good job

Answer (score 4):

As it appears this bug may remain core to Firefox for some time longer, here's a 99% drop-in patch:

```
if(/Firefox\/\d+[\d\.]*/.test(navigator.userAgent)
        && typeof window.DragEvent === 'function'
        && typeof window.addEventListener === 'function') (function(){
    // patch for Firefox bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=505521
    var cx, cy, px, py, ox, oy, sx, sy, lx, ly;
    function update(e) {
        cx = e.clientX; cy = e.clientY;
        px = e.pageX;   py = e.pageY;
        ox = e.offsetX; oy = e.offsetY;
        sx = e.screenX; sy = e.screenY;
        lx = e.layerX;  ly = e.layerY;
    }
    function assign(e) {
        e._ffix_cx = cx; e._ffix_cy = cy;
        e._ffix_px = px; e._ffix_py = py;
        e._ffix_ox = ox; e._ffix_oy = oy;
        e._ffix_sx = sx; e._ffix_sy = sy;
        e._ffix_lx = lx; e._ffix_ly = ly;
    }
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', update, true);
    window.addEventListener('dragover', update, true);
    // bug #505521 identifies these three listeners as problematic:
    // (although tests show 'dragstart' seems to work now, keep to be compatible)
    window.addEventListener('dragstart', assign, true);
    window.addEventListener('drag', assign, true);
    window.addEventListener('dragend', assign, true);

    var me = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(window.MouseEvent.prototype),
        ue = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(window.UIEvent.prototype);
    function getter(prop,repl) {
        return function() {return me[prop] && me[prop].get.call(this) || Number(this[repl]) || 0};
    }
    function layerGetter(prop,repl) {
        return function() {return this.type === 'dragover' && ue[prop] ? ue[prop].get.call(this) : (Number(this[repl]) || 0)};
    }
    Object.defineProperties(window.DragEvent.prototype,{
        clientX: {get: getter('clientX', '_ffix_cx')},
        clientY: {get: getter('clientY', '_ffix_cy')},
        pageX:   {get: getter('pageX', '_ffix_px')},
        pageY:   {get: getter('pageY', '_ffix_py')},
        offsetX: {get: getter('offsetX', '_ffix_ox')},
        offsetY: {get: getter('offsetY', '_ffix_oy')},
        screenX: {get: getter('screenX', '_ffix_sx')},
        screenY: {get: getter('screenY', '_ffix_sy')},
        x:       {get: getter('x', '_ffix_cx')},
        y:       {get: getter('y', '_ffix_cy')},
        layerX:  {get: layerGetter('layerX', '_ffix_lx')},
        layerY:  {get: layerGetter('layerY', '_ffix_ly')}
    });
})();
```

Note, although the OP's question was specific to just 'dragend', this is a fix for all affected events.

It grabs the last accurate coordinates of the mouse from the 'mousemove' and 'dragover' events, and implants them into the affected 'dragstart', 'drag', and 'dragend' events.

Please note, it isn't an *exact* fix. x / y coordinates might be slightly off. Since 'drag' event occurs before 'dragover', it executes with the coordinates from the previous event frame.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you dear sir! I hope Mozzilla will fix this issue soon.

Answer (score 1):

Update March 2022: The bug has finally been assigned to the same person who has been blocking it for 13 years. This was mid October 2021. So after 13 years, a solution is on its way.

Comment: Have anyone checked that he is still alive? No change on this for another year...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with Firefox the other day.

I managed to find a work around although it depends on using a global variable for storing the mouse before and after positions.

The bit that seemed to get things working was to get the pageX and pageY values from the ondrop event instead of the ondragend event.

The only problem is that the ondrop doesn't store the dragged element or the original mouse positions (hence the need for the global variable).

```
var dragDetails = {
   target: null,
   orgMouseX: 0,
   orgMouseY: 0,
   desMouseX: 0,
   desMouseY: 0
}

$("targetElement").on("dragstart", function(event) {
   dragDetails.target = this;
   dragDetails.orgMouseX = event.originalEvent.pageX;
   dragDetails.orgMouseY = event.originalEvent.pageY;
});

$("html").on("drop", function(event) {
   dragDetails.desMouseX = event.originalEvent.pageX;
   dragDetails.desMouseY = event.originalEvent.pageY;
   handleDrag();
});
```

Here is an example in a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/L1b6uz2d/2/

It seems to work on the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Internet Explorer (the accuracy isn't as good on Internet Explorer though) and it works on Android Chrome. Haven't tested any others yet and I'm sure the code can be improved.

I did manage to get it working without the need for a global variable but I had to use the ondrop and then pass the target, pageX and pageY as parameters to the ondragend event (I didn't include a fiddle because the code was very ugly)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("dragover", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(event.pageX)
  }, false);
```

add `console.log (event.pageX)` in `dragover` Listener
http://jsfiddle.net/zfnj5rv4/

Comment: The OP is asking how to solve the problem of event.pageX in `dragend`.  `dragover` occurs when a completely different element is dragging over `this`.  How is that supposed to be used to solve event.pageX missing in `dragend`?

Answer (score -2):

Don't use e.clientX or e.clientY

Use e.pageX and e.pageY or e.targetTouches[0].pageX e.targetTouches[0].pageY (for Touchscreens) instead.

pageX is referring to the document, clientX to the viewport. See also:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX