# onDrag event clientX is always 0 in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've created a video player progress bar on codesandbox.io (https://codesandbox.io/s/seekbar-with-thumbnail-and-time-tooltips-forked-h5x8k?file=/src/Progressbar.tsx), which is working fine on chrome but not on other browsers.

Specially on firefox the progressbar slider isn't working, dragStart and dragEnd event are firing just fine but not the onDrag event.

onDrag event has all the wrong values for clientX clientY etc.

After some googling Ive found about dataTransfer and added that to drag start event handler too...

```
event.dataTransfer.setData("application/x-moz-node", event.target.id);
```

and `event.preventDefault()` on my dragEnd event handler, but still the same.

Can someone help me out here?

Entire code is available at the codesandbox link I've pasted above.

**EDIT: ON DRAG EVENT IS FIRING, BUT WITH THE FOLLOWING PROPERTIES SAME EVERYTIME**

```
screenX: 0

screenY: 0

clientX: 0

clientY: 0

pageX: 0

pageY: 0
```

**IS CAUSING THE ISSUE. WHY IS ALL THIS 0?**

Comment: Are you sure the `drag` event is not fired? It's fired for me, though the `clientX` is 0 and therefore doesn't pass an `if` condition.

Comment: Hey @DanMacák you're right, the drag event IS firing but all the values (clientX clientY etc) are 0. How does one implement a slider in firefox then? There are so many sliders already in so many UI libraries... do you have any idea?

Comment: My guess is that the libraries use a pointer based rather than drag based approach. Let me expand on this in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`event.dataTransfer` is irrelevant here, the actual problem is that Firefox doesn't track pointer position during `drag` events. To understand why, check [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63365865/4256274) to a problem similar to yours.

This means you can't use `drag` to update element's position based on the pointer which is dragging it. What you could use instead is `dragover`:

```
document.addEventListener('dragover', updateProgress)
```

Unlike drag, `dragover` tracks pointer position so you can use it to update the position of your slider. There is one gotcha though. On your page, there might be multiple draggable elements so you might want to check in your ondragover listener which one is being dragged. You can't easily do that though, since the `document` is the target of `dragover`, not the dragged element. So you also need to check which element is being dragged once `dragstart` is fired and maybe clean up the ondragover listener on `dragend`.

The alternative is to use [Pointer events API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events), `pointerdown`, `pointermove` and `pointerup` in particular. The implementation effort is similar, but Pointer events should be more consistent across browsers (contrary to `drag` event) and devices, since Pointer events unifies many kinds of inputs - touch, mouse, pen - behind a single API.

Comment: do you happen to have a good example which elaborates on Pointer events? I ran into issues with drag/drop as well but there is a lot you have to be aware of when trying to get rid of it..

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by having a somewhat global object that saves the current mouse position

```js
    var mousePosition = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
    }
```

And update this with both the mousemove event and the dragover event. The mousemove event doesn't fire while dragging so we rely on the dragover event listener for the update since it has the event.clientY.

```js
   document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
        mousePosition.x = event.clientX;
        mousePosition.y = event.clientY;
    });

   document.addEventListener("dragover", function (event) {
        mousePosition.x = event.clientX;
        mousePosition.y = event.clientY;
    })
```

So you could use the `mousePosition` object anywhere you need to get the mouse position